# Can't navigate to sources for Maven dependencies easily with IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I added a library to maven by searching from within IntelliJ, and I checked the boxes to download sources and javadoc, which Idea tells me it did.

However, in *some* of the library files I click into, it just says "/* compiled code */", even though the exact source code for those files is available in another jar which i can see right there in the project.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the libraries tab in the project settings you'll see that each library can have an entry for its sources jar. If the one you're looking for doesn't have one, add it manually.

This is all a lot easier if you use maven.

Comment: I'm using maven via the IDEA maven plugin, is that not the same?  I do have the sources jar there, but it's like they aren't matching up or something.  If I open the sources jar in IDEA, navigate to a file, and then navigate back to the "normal" one via CMD+CLICK, then I will see the sources, but it's silly to have to do this all the time.

Comment: Have you tried the procedure I outlined above? It'll tell you which jars have sources associated with them. The maven way of doing things only really works if the library's pom file references the sources jar (a lot of open-source libs work this way). If the maven way doesn't work then you have to add them manually.